# Linux deskop environment randomly changed

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, manjaro, desktop-environment

I am on the latest version of Manjaro Linux.

I was just installing eclipse-java (to my /opt), and it works correctly. Then, I wanted to add a shortcut to it to my menu through the “Menu Editor” but I kept clicking on it and nothing popped up. I then tried to open other windows but nothing worked anymore so I just did a reboot.
Now, everything is still there and everything works, but my xfce seems to have reverted to a very strange style, everything is out of place and the whole environment changed, even though it seems I am still in xfce, but perhaps just a completely different configuration.

[image: Screenshot]

How do I get the default manjaro xfce configuration back? Why did this happen?
Thanks anyone!

Comment: First thing to check: are you starting the correct desktop-environment? The DM (desktop-manager, where you get the log in) may have choose a different environment (old version, newer version, etc.). Check also the logs. Maybe the Menu Editor broke a configuration file, so now such file is discarded (and so with default configuration)

Comment: Welcome! Right-click in the panel > Panel > Panel Preferences > Backup and restore. Select a configuaration, optionally you can save the current. Click apply (the gears button). I'm on xubuntu 18, but I guess the options are the same. Tell me if this works.

Comment: "Latest version" should be changed to specify the version.  This question will stay in the system for a long time... long enough that latest version will be meaningless.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Hi! Thanks for the reply, I do not have the "Backup and restore" option.